# Подскажите, нужны ли запятые?

Tags: пунктуация

Фото готового дома, еще не покрашенного, без ограды.

Подскажите, нужна ли, главное, запятая после слова "дома".

Answer (score 2):

Запятая нужна, после существительного обособляется однородный ряд определений, при этом первое согласованное определение выражено причастным оборотом, второе - несогласованное определение.

Вообще говоря, согласованное определение в постпозиции на обособляется только в том случае, если на него падает логическое ударение, тогда нет паузы, например: Тянутся мысли неторопливые, дремотные.

Примечание. В приведенном примере обособленный ряд имеет добавочное значение. В то же время в принципе возможен авторский вариант с противопоставлением и без обособления: Это фотография уже готового дома, а это фото дома еще не покрашенного, без ограды.

Comment: А какое добавочное значение имеет обособленный ряд?

Comment: В приведенном примере основной признак обозначен необособленным прилагательным "готовый", а обособленный ряд называет дополнительные признаки.

Answer (score 0):

Розенталь Д.Э. Параграф 92. 
Обособляются два или больше согласованных одиночных определения, стоящих после определяемого существительного, если последнему предшествует еще одно определение, например: ...Любимые лица, мертвые и живые, приходят на память... (Тургенев); ...Длинные облака, красные и лиловые, сторожили его [солнца] покой... (Чехов).
При отсутствии предшествующего определения два последующих одиночных определения обособляются или не обособляются в зависимости от авторской интонационно-смысловой нагрузки, а также их местоположения (определения, стоящие между подлежащим и сказуемым, обособляются). 
Возможно, здесь по аналогии.

Comment: Основным фактором, влияющим на обособление согласованных определений, является постпозиция, в частности наличие предшествующего определения - это только только сопутствующий фактор. Также может не обособляться определение между подлежащим и сказуемым: Кто-то большой и грузный перемахнул через забор.  Поэтому в каждом случае при решении задачи желательно учитывать влияние ряда факторов, в то время как на каждое готовое правило всегда найдется исключение.